# Comparing parts of Arrays against each other?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I'm really really really not sure what is the best way to approach this. I've gotten as far as I can, but I basically want to scan a user response with an array of words and search for matches so that my AI can tell what mood someone is in based off the words they used. However, I've yet to find a clear or helpful answer. My code is pretty cluttered too because of how many different methods I've tried to use. I either need a way to compare sections of arrays to each other or portions of strings. I've found things for finding a part of an array. Like finding eggs in green eggs and ham, but I've found nothing that finds a section of an array in a section of another array.

```
     public class MoodCompare extends Mood1 {
        public static void MoodCompare(String inputMood){
            int inputMoodLength = inputMood.length();
            int HappyLength = Arrays.toString(Happy).length();
            boolean itWorks = false;

            String[] inputMoodArray = inputMood.split(" ");
            if(Arrays.toString(Happy).contains(Arrays.toString(inputMoodArray)) == true)
                System.out.println("Success!");
```

InputMood is the data the user has input that should have keywords lurking in them to their mood. Happy is an array of the class Mood1 that is being extended. This is only a small piece of the class, much less the program, but it should be all I need to make a valid comparison to complete the class.
If anyone can help me with this, you will save me hours of work. So THANK YOU!!!

Comment: you are missing some brackets

Comment: You can use [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) to get portions of `String`s

Comment: Yeah brackets are missing because I copy and pasted a section of the code, but I promise they are in the original.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating strings will be nicer when you do not use the relative primitive arrays, where you have to walk through yourself etcetera. A Dutch proverb says: not seeing the wood through the trees.

In this case it seems you check words of the input against a set of words for some mood.

Lets use java collections:

Turning an input string into a list of words:

```
String input = "...";
List<String> sentence = Arrays.asList(input.split("\\W+"));
sentence.remove("");
```

`\\W+` is a sequence of one or more non-word characters. Mind "word" mean `A-Za-z0-9_`.

Now a mood would be a set of unique words:

```
Set<String> moodWords = new HashSet<>();
Collections.addAll(moodWords, "happy", "wow", "hurray", "great");
```

Evaluation could be:

```
int matches = 0;
for (String word : sentence) {
    if (moodWords.contains(word)) {
        ++matches;
    }
}
int percent = sentence.isEmpty() ? 0 : matches * 100 / sentence.size();
System.out.printf("Happiness: %d %%%n", percent);
```

In java 8 even compacter.

```
int matches = sentence.stream().filter(moodWords::contains).count();
```

***Explanation:***

The foreach-word-in-sentence takes every word. For every word it checks whether it is contained in `moodWords`, the set of all mood words.

The percentage is taken over the number of words in the sentence being moody. The boundary condition of an empty sentence is handled by the if-then-else expression `... ? ... : ...` - an empty sentence given the arbitrary percentage 0%.

The printf format used %d for the integer, %% for the percent sign `%` (self-escaped) and %n for the line break character(s).

Comment: Does this take into consideration having multiple words that could match and does it compare to the total number of words instead of the number of characters to find percent? It appears that way to me, but I am not the best at programming, so I could be wrong. It appears the token method might be the easiest from what I have seen.

Comment: @TimGass have added the explanation to the answer, so otbers may benefit from it too. And yes, sentence "happy wow rain happy snow" would give 60 % for "happy, wow".

Comment: Set<String> moodWords = new HashSet<>();
Collections.addAll(moodWords, "happy", "wow", "hurray", "great"); Did noy work. Error: syntax error on this token "(", delete this token.

Comment: The call to `Collections.addAll` must be inside a function body. My guess: you placed all immediately in the class body. There only declations of fields and functions (methods) are allowed. And at the '(' the compiler sees that it is not a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you mean something like this?

```
String words[] = {"green", "eggs", "and", "ham"};
String response = "eggs or ham";
Mood mood = new Mood();

for(String foo : words)
{
   if(response.contains(foo))
   {
      //Check if happy etc...
      if(response.equals("green")
         mood.sad++;
      ...
   } 

}

System.out.println("Success");
...

//CheckMood() etc... other methods.
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm on break at work and all I do is C# and ASP.NET. Takes a toll on the java brain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tokens.

Every time that the program needs to compare the contents of a row from one array to the other array, just tokenize the contents in parallel and compare them.

Visit the following Java Doc page for farther reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

or even view the following web pages:
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/72regular/Tokenizer.java.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it. This is way easier.